# Flask cannot get JSON from send_file Response object

Tags: python, flask

Using Flask, I've attempted to load a static JSON file using `send_from_directory`. From this I get a `Response` object. I cannot get this object in JSON format; however.

```
courses = send_from_directory("static/", "courses.json");
courses["math"] # not a JSON - cannot get math element from loaded courses
jsonify(courses) # Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

How would one go about converting a response into JSON format, then?

edit: To clarify - I'm not looking to return a file and a JSON. I am seeking to get a `dict` from a JSON file that is located within "/static" in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import json

courses = send_from_directory("static/", "courses.json");

courses_dict = json.loads(courses)
print(courses_dict["math"])
```